# Using HttpModule for 2FA (One Time Password Method) in OWA

Tags: c#, iis, exchange-server, httpmodule, outlook-web-app

I have created a httpmodule for OWA (Outlook web app) for its 2 factor Authentication through OTP(One Time Password).

In Application_BeginRequest method context field contains **password + OTP** in this `context.Request.Form["password"]`

I replaced OTP string with `string.Empty` in this `context.Request.Form["password"]`. but still on OWA login method it does not login.

If I don't replace string and send only password in password field, It logs in perfectly.

I updated the context.Request.Form["password"] field through reflection. In Application_EndRequest password field got updated, as I checked into the httpmodule logs.

Any idea how i could achieve this? 
What I actually need is **password + OTP** in this field `context.Request.Form["password"]` , then call OTP Server for its verification and update the `context.Request.Form["password"]` field with only password in it. so that if OTP Server respond with valid user It should log in with OWA. but in my case if update `context.Request.Form["password"]` field log in failed.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I am also trying to develop OTP solution for OWA. Any help will be appreciated.